# ListActivities setItemChecked in onListItemClick not working

Tags: android, listview, listactivity

I have this code here:

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    if(l.isItemChecked(position))
        l.setItemChecked(position, false);
    else
        l.setItemChecked(position, true);
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Mission: " + ((TreeNode)l.getItemAtPosition(position)).getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

It works as far as the debugger goes, but the setItemChecked never seems to really set the item both graphically I do not see the check box appear and then on the next click through the isItemChecked still returns false.

Not sure what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

just try this.....
make android:focusable="false" to check box

Answer (score 0):

have you tried refreshing the adapter of the list ?

```
l.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: It seems the only method I have available is getAdapter().notifyAll(); which complains about the thread or something ont being locked if I try to add that at the bottom of the onListItemClick method?

Comment: You have to cast the adapter into your custom adapter, such as BaseAdapter etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you set your ListView `Adapter` to `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` and you View with checkBox would implement `Checkable` interface, you wouldn't need to handle toggling checkbox by yourself